# OrderBy with built in condition

Tags: c#, lambda

I have a list of trips that I need to sort by the time at which they start.  Certain trips do not have a time, and these are stored in the database as 12:00am. I am currently sorting the list as follows:

```
trips = trips.OrderBy(t => t.PickupTime);
```

The problem is that I want this to sort such that the 12:00am trips are put at the bottom of the list.  Changing the database is not an option.  Is there an elegant, clean way to tell the OrderBy to treat a time of 12:00am as being the highest value (probably use `DateTime.MaxValue`)?

I am aware that I could just use `trips.Sort(delegate(..));`, however I'd like to avoid this if possible.  Also, I am not able to filter out these trips and then add them back on to the end.  It wasn't received happily in code review.

Comment: Why not just filter the 12am ones out, sort, and then re-add them at the end?

Comment: What type `PickupTime` has? Is it database query or in-memory query? If it is database query, then what database you have and what Linq provider you are using?

Comment: Were this pure SQL I'd suggest you use the [NullIf statement](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177562.aspx).  However, since this looks like LINQ, you could use the LINQ equivalent:  http://forums.asp.net/t/1329185.aspx

Comment: @ashes999 That was my initial approach, my superior was unhappy with it though.

Comment: @RhinoFeeder that's probably important to mention in your question as a constraint (although why he would be unhappy is beyond me).

Comment: Is it LINQ to Entities? LINQ to SQL? LINQ to Objects?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could just use the conditional operator in your order by

```
var midnight = new DateTime(0).TimeOfDay;

trips = trips.OrderBy(t=> t.PickupTime.TimeOfDay == midnight ?
                             DateTime.MaxValue :
                             t.PickupTime);
```

Comment: Sorry for the previous comment, I typed your solution in wrong ;)  This worked for me, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You can use `OrderBy` with `ThenBy`:

```
trips = trips.OrderBy(t => t.TimeOfDay == (new DateTime(2014, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0)).TimeOfDay))
             .ThenBy(t => t.PickupTime);
```

It will sort by *is time 00:00:00* first, and because `false` comes before `true` in that kind of sorts, you'll get non-midnight values first. `ThenBy` will sort non-midnight values using standard `DateTime` comparison.

Comment: Interesting, I didn't know you could sort by `bool`s / that `bool`s [implement `IComparable<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh924432.aspx).

Comment: very nice, making `new DateTime(2014, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0)` a readonly member would be even better.

Comment: @IsmailHawayel Yes, you should probably store it as variable somewhere. Otherwise new `DateTime` instance will be created for every item.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest writing your own comparer that inherits IComparer and use that in the OrderBy in place of the default comparer. If you give me what type PickupTime is I can give you a more specific example, but here is a string comparer I have that ensures empty strings are last:

```
public class EmptyStringsAreLast : IComparer<string>
    {
        public int Compare(string x, string y)
        {
            if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(y) && !String.IsNullOrEmpty(x))
            {
                return -1;
            }
            else if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(y) && String.IsNullOrEmpty(x))
            {
                return 1;
            }
            else
            {
                return String.Compare(x, y);
            }
        }
    }
```

You would use this like:

```
//assuming Person has a Name property that is a string
IEnumerable<Person> bunchOfPeople = getPeople();
bunchOfPeople.OrderBy(p => p.Name, new EmptyStringsAreLast());
```